# Setup Proxy for Azure Blob Storage URLs

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, azure-blob-storage, reverse-proxy

I have an application that allows user uploads of images. These images are stored on Azure Blob storage, from which they *technically* could be accessed via a direct URL.

However, I don't want to expose the address of my blob storage directly to the users (who are logged in via Entra ID credentials). I also want to avoid the pain of pulling SAS tokens for each image for each page.

**Is there a way to proxy calls from my application to Azure storage and return the result without having to keep the whole object in memory?**

1. User calls `https://myapp.com/attachment/image001.jpg`
2. A controller receives the request and verifies the user's authz for that endpoint
3. Controller and makes a subsequent call to [https://myappsstorage.blob.core.windows.net/appattachmentcontainer/image001.jpg`](https://myappsstorage.blob.core.windows.net/appattachmentcontainer/image001.jpg%60)
4. The controller, without needing to allocate the result or keep the whole downloaded image in memory, forwards the result back to the original caller.

I've done this before but I've always just downloaded the whole result and kept it in memory before returning back to the original caller. I'd like to improve on this but not sure of the mechanism within .net to do it.

### Sample

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Attachment()
{

    using var httpClient = new HttpClient();

    // NOTE: This is allocating the whole stream, no?
    var downloadedImage = await httpClient.GetStreamAsync(
        "https://127.0.0.1:10000/devstoreaccount1/magic-scaler/04108_lakeohau_3840x2400.jpg");
    return File(downloadedImage, "image/jpg", DateTimeOffset.UtcNow, EntityTagHeaderValue.Any);
}
```

Comment: Per my understanding, we can use [Azure Blob API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/blob-service-rest-api) to hide the item link into your App. In your Controller, providing an action which implement the list API so that you can display all the items in the view. Then creating another action method to receive which blob item is required to download and then compose the download URL and get the blob item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I don't want to expose the address of my blob storage directly to the users (who are logged in via Entra ID credentials). I also want to avoid the pain of pulling SAS tokens for each image for each page.

I agree with Tiny Wang's comment. You can use the **`Azure Blob API`** to hide the item link in your app.

1. create an action method in your controller that implements the list API to display all the items in the view.
2. you can create another action method to receive which blob item is required to download and then compose the download URL and get the blob item.

Here is the code that you can implement in your controller:

**Code:**

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Azure.Storage.Blobs;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class AttachmentController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly BlobServiceClient _blobServiceClient;

    public AttachmentController(BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient)
    {
        _blobServiceClient = blobServiceClient;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> ListAttachments()
    {
        var containerClient = _blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient("sample");

        var blobs = new List<string>();

        await foreach (var blobItem in containerClient.GetBlobsAsync())
        {
            blobs.Add(blobItem.Name);
        }

        return Ok(blobs);
    }

    [HttpGet("{imageName}")]
    public IActionResult GetAttachment(string imageName)
    {
        var blobServiceClient = _blobServiceClient;
        var containerClient = blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient("sample");
        var blobClient = containerClient.GetBlobClient(imageName);

        var sasUri = blobClient.GenerateSasUri(Azure.Storage.Sas.BlobSasPermissions.Read, DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddHours(1));
        var signedUrl = blobClient.Uri + sasUri.Query;
        return Redirect(signedUrl);
    }
}
```

The above code uses the **`Azure.Storage.Blobs`** package to interact with Azure Blob Storage. The **`ListAttachments`** method lists all the blobs in the **`sample`** container and returns their names as a list.

The **`GetAttachment`** method takes an image name as a parameter, generates a SAS token with read permission for the blob, and constructs a signed URL with the SAS token. It then redirects the user to the signed URL.

**Output:**
Now, using Postman, I can list and get the image.

**List:**

```
https://localhost:xxx/attachment
```

[image: List of images]

**View the image:**

```
https://localhost:xxxx/attachment/<your listing image name>
```

[image]

**Reference:**

[Get started with Azure Blob Storage and .NET - Azure Storage | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-dotnet-get-started?tabs=azure-ad#build-your-application)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. I now see what @Tiny-Wang was saying in his comment. I think the key thing here is passing a redirection and generating the SAS URI. Your example of that is very helpful!